# Eclipse Terminal showing old java and Maven versions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I updated my JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME for jdk1.6 and Maven 3.2.5. The cmd shows the updated jdk and maven. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg7ks.png)

But the Eclipse terminal is still showing the old jdk and for maven it gives error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlGDX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZDNL.png)

Please help me update the java and maven version in eclipse terminal

Comment: You want to go back from Java 15 to Java 6?

Comment: Do not post links to images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/296328

Comment: Yes, I want to go back to JDK 6 from JDK 15